# Callable Statement in Java Not Working

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

There appears to be something wrong with my JDBC driver.

I'm attempting to execute the following java code:

```
String sql = "{call get_samp_stud_no_out (?,?,?)}";
CallableStatement call = conn.prepareCall(sql);
call.setInt("objId1", 1);
call.setInt("objId2", 2);
call.setInt("objId3", 3);
ResultSet results = call.executeQuery();
```

And I'm getting:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybCallableStatement.setInt(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
```

BTW its a sybase database.
I have tried both jconn2.jar and jconn3.jar.

And other stored proc which accepts String parameteres:

```
String sql = "{call get_samp_stud_no_name (?,?,?)}";
    CallableStatement call = conn.prepareCall(sql);
    call.setString("objId1", "nappa");
    call.setString("objId2", "vegeta");
    call.setString("objId3", "frieza");
    ResultSet results = call.executeQuery();
```

And the exception for this is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybCallableStatement.setString(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Comment: Is argument for get_samp_stud_no_out are Integer??

Comment: Yes I its Integer. And I also tried the same with another stored proc which accepts String parameteres and i get the same exception

Answer (score 0):

In Sybase drivers there are lot of issues with named parameters, I think this causes your problem.
Try:

```
call.setString("@objId1", "nappa");
call.setString("@objId2", "vegeta");
call.setString("@objId3", "frieza");
```

or

```
call.setString(1, "nappa");
call.setString(2, "vegeta");
call.setString(3, "frieza");
```

Comment: The first one returns the same exception and the positional parameter was working fine from the beginning.But i want the first syntax to work.

Comment: another 2 options: 1. use call.execute() 2. register out param if exists

Comment: Tried call.execute() got the same exception and proc does not return anything.

Comment: Which driver exactly do you use?

Comment: Did you register the return parameter? `cstmt.setString("p1", value1); 
cstmt.setString("p2", val2); 
cstmt.registerOutParameter("outRes", Types.String);
cstmt.execute();
String res = cstmt.getString("outRes");`

Comment: Tried that too but still returns the same exception.

Comment: But the surprise is that in the exception description it points to the line which appears after I register the output parameter.Any idea why it is pointing to this line?

Comment: I guess this line is the 'execute()' call, because it fails only upon execution. Sorry, I am also lost here, don't know why it fails...

Comment: No its not the execute() call line that come 2 lines below.The exception is pointing out to a line where I set a parameter which i pass to the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code like this:

```
String sql = "{?=call get_samp_stud_no_out (?,?,?)}";
CallableStatement call = conn.prepareCall(sql);

call.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
call.setInt(2, 10);
call.setInt(3, 20);
call.setInt(4, 30);
call.execute();
int retVal = call.getInt(1); // return value
call.close();
```

Comment: Tried this got the same exception.BTW the exception is pointing to this line: `call.setInt("objId1", 2);`

Comment: Hmm ok, can you pls try modified code now? (Replaced `executeQuery()` with `execute()`) and changed the order of `setInt` calls as first parameter is supposed to be position and 2nd parameter is your value.

Comment: Tried this and got the same exception.

Comment: One more edit: changed the order of setInt calls as first parameter is supposed to be position and 2nd parameter is your value. Pls try and let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion caused the positional parameteres are working fine but when i use the actual names the exception is caused.All my above comments were for the one which has names in place of positional parameteres.